# Shell Script CGI to call two different scripts (using Form Post method)

Tags: bash, shell, cgi

I'm creating a Shell Bash CGI script which actually in turn using HTML forms calls two scrips ( one Perl and Other Python).

I'm successfully able to run the script individually i.e. one script at a time , but when I not getting the logic to call both the child scripts from the Parent Sheel Bash Script.

I want to run the first child script if Form 1 is selected and run the 2nd child script if Form 2 is selected ?

One more question , using Get meathod show the passpord , what will be the best option to hide  the password strings ?

Here is the Code :

```
(HTML Form starts here)
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Fview"
echo "</title></head><body>"
echo "<h1>Please enter device name in the Box</h1>"
echo '<form method=GET action="support">'\
        '<table nowrap> <tr><td>Device</TD><TD><input type="text" name="val_x" size=12></td></tr>'\
        '<tr><td>Username</TD><TD><input type="text" name="val_y" size=12></td></tr>'\
        '<tr><td>Password: </TD><TD><input type="password" name="val_z" size=12></td></tr></tr></table>' 
echo '<br><input type="submit" value="Get Qkview"> <input type="reset" value="Reset"></form> '
echo '<form method=GET action="support">'\
        '<table nowrap> <tr><td>Device</TD><TD><input type="text" name="val_a" size=12></td></tr>'\
        '<tr><td>Username</TD><TD><input type="text" name="val_b" size=12></td></tr>'\
        '<tr><td>Password: </TD><TD><input type="password" name="val_c" size=12></td></tr></tr></table>' 
echo '<br><input type="submit" value="Get VIP"> <input type="reset" value="Reset"></form> '


#HTML ends here , you can see two forms 

PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/ucb:/usr/opt/bin:/usr/local/bin:"
export $PATH
if [ "$REQUEST_METHOD" != "GET" ]; then
        echo "<hr>Script Error:"\
             "<br>Usage error, cannot complete request, REQUEST_METHOD!=GET."\
             "<br>Check your FORM declaration and be sure to use METHOD=\"GET\".<hr>"
        exit 1
  fi
  # If no search arguments, exit gracefully now.
  if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
        exit 0
  else
     # No looping this time, just extract the data you are looking for with sed:
    XX=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_x=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
    YY=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_y=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
    ZZ=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_z=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
    AA=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_a=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
    BB=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_b=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
    CC=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*val_c=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`


#Here are the two child scripts . But am able to call the health_ui.pl but not view.py
         commandline="/home/u1/scripts/health_ui.pl $AA $BB $CC"
         commandline="/home/u2/scripts/view.py $XX $YY $ZZ"
         $commandline
         echo "done:"


  fi

echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'

exit 0
```

Comment: As far as I know the line `#! PATH TO SCRIPT BINARY` should always be the first one in a script. What about `view.py`? Is that the case for that one?

Comment: @MarcusRickert Indeed the "shebang", that special line you mention MUST be the _first_ line in the script, otherwise it is just a simply comment. However this does not mean that the script does not execute, that is a question of _how_ the script is called. The shebang allows to call a script just by it's path, because the calling shell uses that line to determine the required interpreter that has to be used to interpret the script. Without the shebang you can execute the script, but you have to specify the interpreter manually: `python <path/to/script.py>`

Comment: @arkascha: Thank you for clarifying! Looking at the code above I would assume that the scripts do need a correct shebang, don't they?

Comment: @marcusRickert   ..HTML Form starts here  ..I mentioned as description to make people understand here.... These line are not actually in the actual code . I made the modification in the question now

Comment: @MarcusRickert That depends on the setup of the http server, I'd say. If I understand the OP correct, then the scripts are meant to be executed as cgi scripts (thus the http server involved). How such a server calls scripts depends on how its cgi service is configured (the handler specified). But indeed it appears the OP tries to directly call scripts from within a cgi script, so yes, those (perl and python) scripts either require a correct and working shebang, or they must be called with an explicit interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

According to the small discussion in the comments above this might be the issue:

```
commandline="perl /home/u1/scripts/health_ui.pl $AA $BB $CC"
$commandline
echo "first script done."
commandline="python -c /home/u2/scripts/view.py $XX $YY $ZZ"
$commandline
echo "second script done."
```

not that *both* $commandline values have to be "executed" and that the (corect?) interpreter has to precede the script paths, if no correct shebang is specified as the first line of those scripts.

Comment: The prob here is that .... in the HTML it has 2 GET statement.. I somehow need to find way ....how I can map the one GET statement to the commandline.    Because if I try individually it works ...But if I put both ...it takes the first child script

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you here, maybe there is a miss understanding... Is it correct that you want to execute _two_ scripts (the perl and the python one) from within the bash script, which itself is called via cgi? If so, you probably want to execute those two scripts in a serial manner, so one after another? Then where is the problem with the arguments? note that in the code snippet above there are _two_ lines executing the previously defined "commandline", one per script. You cannot do that in _one_ call, except if you concatenate the definitions, which you did not do.

Comment: let me explain you again i want to create two form in one CGI script. and want to put a login that if first button is press then it should execute first commandline and if second submit button is press then it should run second commandline.

Comment: Ah, ok, sorry. Indeed that detail completely skipped my eye... So you need to code a conditional (`if` command) which evaluates the existence of each forms submit button. Or, easier, you add a hidden input variable to each form _with the same name_, say "action", so that you have to consider only a single variable from the query string. You find the query string inside an environment variable setup for the cgi script. Not sure, never used bash as cgi script, but it appears that you have to parse that string yourself... That would certainly be easier if you use a script interpreter like `php` .

Comment: But in all cases what has been said about the shebang line is true. Otherwise you will not be able to execute the scripts.